# Hiding and showing view prevents fragment change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I am having an issue with swapping out fragments,the steps are as follows:

- Set loading screen visibility to visible
- Start webcall
- in callback, hide loading screen
- in callback still, perform fragment transaction to replace fragment

Following these steps, my fragment does not change and I remain on the fragment which displayed the loading screen.

My fragment transaction will successfully complete if I:

- Do not show the loading screen or,
- hide the loading screen after the transaction

But, if I hide the loading screen after my transaction, the fragment does not show and I only receive a white background. I have been experiencing this problem for several days and have contemplated it extensively but cannot think of what could be causing it.

Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="#40000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
                    android:text="Loading..."
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/nav_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

EDIT:

show loading screen:

```
public void showLoading(String message){
    tvLoadingText.setText(message);
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

hide loading screen:

```
public void hideLoading(){
    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

## EDIT 2:

I commented above the method signatures so that it is easy to follow the steps, this is another bug I saw weeks ago but somewhat different, instead of trying to change the fragments, I am trying to show a Snackbar but it will not show unless I disable hideLoading() or showLoading().

LoginFragment:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements ILoginView{

    private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "error message";

    ILoginPresenter mLoginPresenter;
    ILoginModel mLoginModel;
    BaseActivity baseActivity;

    @Bind(R.id.etUsername)EditText etUsername;
    @Bind(R.id.etPassword)EditText etPassword;
    @Bind(R.id.etSFApiKey)EditText etToken;

    public static LoginFragment newInstance(String errorMessage){

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ERROR_MESSAGE, errorMessage);
        LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
        loginFragment.setArguments(args);

        return loginFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String errorMessage = getArguments().getString(ERROR_MESSAGE);
        mLoginModel = new LoginModel(getActivity());
        mLoginPresenter = new LoginPresenter(this, mLoginModel);
        baseActivity = (BaseActivity) getActivity();
        showErrorMessage(errorMessage);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void showMainActivity() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
        getActivity().finish();
    }

    //4th step, hide the loading screen, show a snackbar... 
    //except showing the snackbar doesn't work
    @Override
    public void showErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        baseActivity.hideLoading();
        baseActivity.snackbar(errorMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    }

    @Override
    public void hideToken() {
        etToken.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //If you're not familiar with ButterKnife, 
    //this is where my button's onclick listener is set
    //first step, press login, next step in LoginPresenter
    @OnClick(R.id.bLogin) void login() {
        baseActivity.showLoading("Logging in...");
        mLoginPresenter.login(
                etUsername.getText().toString(),
                etPassword.getText().toString(),
                etToken.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

LoginPresenter:

```
public class LoginPresenter implements ILoginPresenter{

    ILoginView mLoginView;
    ILoginModel mLoginModel;

    public LoginPresenter(ILoginView loginView, ILoginModel loginModel){
        mLoginView = loginView;
        mLoginModel = loginModel;

        if(CCMobile.crm != CCMobile.SALESFORCE)
            mLoginView.hideToken();
    }

    //Second step, attempt web call login, next step in callback
    @Override
    public void login(String username, String password, String token) {
        if((username.equals("") || password.equals("")))
            mLoginView.showErrorMessage("All fields required");
        else
            mLoginModel.login(username, password + token, mLoginCallback);

    }

    LoginCallback mLoginCallback = new LoginCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String request, String response) {
            super.onSuccess(request, response);
            mLoginView.showMainActivity();
        }

        //Third step, force a failure
        @Override
        public void onFailure(String request, String response, String errorMessage) {
            super.onFailure(request, response, errorMessage);
            if(errorMessage != null)
                mLoginView.showErrorMessage(errorMessage);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: link the activity's code

Comment: I added the requested code.

Comment: Can you post the entire activity code as it is, and not just snippets?

Comment: Perhaps I can create a simple activity to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Why not use a Fragment for the loading components, and use the container layout to hold it. And when the loading is complete, replace the fragment as you do in provided code.

Comment: I made another edit with a simpler and more complete example with code to follow.

Comment: So, I discovered that the issue was that I was performing animations and getting an exception (that wasn't being shown in my stacktrace) `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on Looper threads` and this only happened when I came back from a webcall/async task. Any ideas how to solve this?